# Please explain me the need for appending '\0' while converting string to char

Tags: c++, mysql

While using proc/mysql for c++ I have taken string as user input and converted into char via `strcpy(c,s.c_str());` function, where `c` is the binding variable through which I'll add value in the database table and `s` is the string (user input),  it is working fine but my teacher is asking me append `'\0'` at the end - I can't understand the reason why I need to?

Comment: You don't with `strcpy`, it is guaranteed to copy the null-terminator anyway. (assuming the destination is large enough, which you are supposed to guarantee).

Comment: Because your teacher doesn't know what he or she is doing.

Comment: First of all you can bind `s.c_str()` (assuming `s` lives long enough) directly, instead of copying into buffer and binding that.

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher is deluded.

`c_str()` in itself appends a zero [or rather, `std::string` reserves space for an extra character when creating the string, and makes sure this is zero at least at the point of `c_str()` returning - in C++11, it is guaranteed that there is an extra character space filled with zero at the end of the string, always].

You DO need a zero at the end of a string to mark the end of the string in a C-style string, such as those used by `strcpy`.

[As others have pointed out, you should also check that the string fits before copying, and I would suggest reject if it won't fit, as truncating it will lead to other problems - as well as checking that there isn't any sql-injection attacks and a multitude of other things required for "good pracice in an SQL environment"]

Answer (score 0):

While the teacher is deluded on the appending '\0' to the string, your code exhibits another very bad bug.

You should **never** use strcpy in such a fashion. You should always use some routine which controls the nubmer of characters copied, like `strncpy()`, or other alternatives, and provide it with the size of receiving variable. Otherwise you are just asking for troubles.

Comment: `strncpy` produces more problems than it solves. It's a very specialized function, and is not a substitute for careful programming and `strcpy`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I was already ready to upvote the comment (I am well aware of strncpy issues...) but than I have read 'careful programming and strcpy' and all upvoting desire vanished. Couldn't disagree more.

Comment: Have you looked at the amount of beginners' code on this site that uses `strncpy` in ways that will be disastrous? It's not designed to be a "safe" `strcpy`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, and I never said it was. However, this is the only standartized way to overcome buffer overrun issues associated with strcpy, so absent `strlcpy` in standard we have to deal with what we have.

Comment: Nonsense. <g> The way to overcome buffer overrun issues associated with `strcpy` is to know how long your source is and how long your target is. Granted, I'm not a big fan of so-called "safe" versions of string functions, but, really, it's not that hard to make appropriate checks when you create or read a source string and when you create the target buffer. Pushing those sensible checks into an after-the-fact test of whether you did those things right is an admission of failure.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I am not sure what is your background, but let me tell you this much - in many places I've worked (and you know those companies from the news on their technical leadership) a use of strcpy would automatically cause a review rejection. Plain and simple. And I fully concur.

Comment: I'm sure you're right that companies design review systems to try to compensate for design errors with procrustean rules. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker, are you one of the original developers of OpenSSL? With such an attitude I won't be surprised.

Comment: In his book "Quality is Free", Philip Crosby makes an analogy between software development and automobile manufacturing. If cars are coming off the assembly line without their headlights, the manufacturer adds the headlights, **and** looks at the station where the headlights are supposed to be added and figures out why they're not getting put on. Software development systems should do the same thing: if the system produces buggy code, figure out why, and fix the underlying problem rather than patching up the errors after they're made.

Comment: Re: OpenSSL. Please don't stoop to insults when people say things you don't want to accept.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I did not mean to insult. But does it insult you when the real-life cataclisims caused by viewes similar to yours are pointed out?

Comment: "I did not mean to insult." Of course you did. And you've mischaracterized what I said to make that fit. This thread is over.

Comment: Of course it is. There is nothing else to add here.

Answer (score -1):

Just guessing, it's a protection against buffer overflow. If `c` is only `N` bytes long and `s.c_str()` returns a pointer to a `N+k` length string, you'd write `k` bytes after `c`, which is bad.

Now let's say (if you didn't SEGFAULT already) you pass this `c` NUL-terminated string to a C function, you have no guarantee that the `\0` you wrote after `c` is still there. This C function will then read an undefined amount of bytes after `c`, which is <s>badder</s> worse.

Anyway, use `::strncpy()`:

```
char c[64];
::strncpy(c, s.c_str(), sizeof(c));
c[sizeof(c)-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: If `s.c_str()` is longer than `c`, you are already in a whole heap of trouble. Truncating the string in `c` doesn't save you because it's already too late.

Comment: @BoBTFish I agree. I also kind of understand that the teacher is following old habits.